# Не получается переадресация React v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const Link = require('../models/Link')
const router = Router()

router.get('/:code', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const link = await Link.findOne({ code: req.params.code })

    if (link) {
      link.clicks++
      await link.save()
      return res.redirect(link.from)
    }

    res.status(404).json('Ссылка не найдена')

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова' })
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Не работает переадресация. На старой версии React данный код работал